# Does tightening abdominal muscles reduce abdominal fat?

Tags: exercise, body-fat

I have heard someone said that always conscious tighten abdominal muscles would help me reduce abdominal fat.

1. Is that true?
2. Does tightening abdominal muscles **all the time** not harm my body?
3. If 2 is false , when and what situation I can tighten my abdominal muscles?

---

Because I don't like spend time to do real exercise, the situations when I would do this activity are when I:

1. Sit in front of computer
2. Walk or ride bike (Does walking conflict with *Tightening abdominal muscles*?)
3. Riding motorbike
4. Eating? (I don't think it is safe while eating, or it force me eat less? I also see some articles say *Tighten abdominal muscles* would improve the digestive function)

Are above situations fine to do such exercise?

Answer (score 2):

> conscious tighten abdominal muscles would help me reduce abdominal fat.

**No it wont.**

> Does tightening abdominal muscles all the time not harm my body?

To build muscle you essentially need to damage it so that it comes back stronger when it recovers/rebuilds. This is the foundation of developing strength and building muscle (Cell water/glucose biology aside). Exercises like squats and deadlifts mean you need to brace your core (tense your abs), the muscle development from this isn't that fact you are bracing but is caused by the really heavy weight you are trying to move, the muscles are doing work to stabilise.

You might cause yourself to get haemorrhoids (I have heard this can happen) or you may develop really good kegal muscles (I know this can happen) but you won't build abs or reduce belly fat.

---

## However...

There is a big glaring issue with answering the question "it is suitable to do this exercise to reduce my belly fat" in the assumption that ANY exercise will spot reduce fat deposits.

## [You cannot target weight loss to anywhere on your body. It is not possible](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast).

On the physical fitness SE and [we get this question a lot](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=belly%20fat%20abdominals).

### we get it nearly every day...

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/are-ab-exercises-more-useful-to-reduce-belly-fat-than-other-exercises

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/118/will-daily-push-ups-help-to-get-rid-of-my-belly-fat

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/what-should-i-do-to-remove-my-belly-fat

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/is-it-possible-to-lose-weight-on-some-special-parts-of-body

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/what-should-i-do-to-remove-my-belly-fat

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/when-fat-is-burnt-where-is-it-taken-from/6251#6251

Answer (score 1):

There's two myths with a grain of truth a the root in your question.

**The myth of spot reduction**
You can't influence where your body loses fat, only if and how much. See [JJosaur's great answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/8740/413) to this.
The kernel of truth is that if you improve your posture by strenghtening your core muscle, you may appear to have less belly fat. The appearance of a fat belly is often partially due to a hollow back. I don't know you and your back so I don't know if this applies to you.

**The myth of multitasking**
You won't do an effective exercise without dedicating time and concentration to it. Fortunately 10-20 min every few days can help a lot. But when you train, you need to train, you need to concentrate on the exercises and your body. Form the habit, stick with it for a while, then it will become normal and easy to dedicate some time to your body.
The kernel of truth: When you develop a proper feel for your body and where your spine should be in a neutral position through exercise, you can should self check your posture often to make sure you don't slouch in an unhealthy way. This is helpful and healthy, just not exercise.

I suggest to think more about what your goals are (why do you want to loose belly fat) and then come back here or to fitness.SE for targeted training advice.